# Neural network accuracy improvement by using polynomials

Tags: math, deep-learning, neural-network

I am new to the theory and history behind Neural networks and came to know that our main neuron activation function is a linear expression that is of the form

w1 x1 + w2 x2 + w3 x3 +...+b

my question why not use a higher degree polynomial expression instead ? that is like

a1 (w1 x1 + w2 x2 + w3 x3...+b)^n + a2(w1 x1 + w2 x2 + w3 x3...+b)^(n-1) + a3(w1 x1 + w2 x2 + w3 x3...+b)^(n-2)+...+an

would this improve accuracy assuming an ideal limitless computation,sorry if this questions sounds stupid

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a field of active research with [GMDH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_method_of_data_handling) networks, where the familiar weighted sums are replaced by Kolmogorov-Gabor polynomial transfer functions.
Working with multidimensional data, a 'complete' polynomial with all cross terms would get really large. In the process of training a GMDH network, a polynomial of the form

[image: eq1]

is adaptively formed, appending cross terms until a target complexity is reached. This is nice, as it works with (unknown) cross dependencies in the input data and prevents over- and underfitting. It's however really demanding to correctly design and implement. Also, the math is more involved, leading to longer computation.

On the other hand, 'normal' ANNs come with the [Universal Approximation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem), which allows them to (approximately) fit any arbitrary function. This makes them easy to design, as you don't really have to think about the shape (or even dimensionality) of the function you want to fit.
I don't think the UAT has been proven for GMDH networks (yet), which limits their application.

So, kinda, yeah. Given unlimited computation and perfect design, you could probably design better networks using more involved transfer functions, but since their design is so vastly easier, the weighted sum formulation is ubiquitous.